# Is it possible to test card mask number if it's applepay/googlepay or not?

Tags: payment, credit-card, applepay, google-pay

I have card numbers in format like `123456xxxxxx7890`. How can i test if it's regular card or any other service like ApplePay/GooglePay/etc?

Just boolean answer yes/no is more than enough for my needs. Is there any logic? Or database?

I've tried to look up at binlist.net service but it doesn't detect it unfortunately (shows wrong banks for 10 card IINs that i have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we will never know if the card is regular card or applepay /google pay card

applepay/gpay generates a unique card number for each original card and we cannot obtain the original card details from it